# Login Failed for user Using SignalR and Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I have implemented SignalR in my ASP.NET WebForms application and am successfully connecting to the hub. However, when a call is made to the database (SQL Server) I get `Login failed for user 'MY_DOMAIN\MY_PC_NAME'`. Note that the user being failed is the PC name and not the user I am impersonating (see below).

My Web.Config is set to impersonate a user who does have access to the database and this works for all calls made to the database that are not via SignalR processes.

IIS is set to use Windows Authentication for the application (and also has ASP.NET Impersonation enabled).

During debug of the SignalR process, the `Context.User.Identity` is the user that is authenticated in the browser session.

Is there a way to ensure that the impersonated user in the Web.Config is honored by SignalR when making SQL calls?

For reference:

Impersonate Tag in Web.Config: `<identity impersonate="true" userName="MY_DOMAIN\MY_USER" password="MY_PASSWORD" />`

Connection String in Web.Config: `<add name="SiteDatabase" connectionString="Server=SERVER_NAME; Database=DATABASE_NAME; Integrated Security=SSPI" />`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the AppPool identity in IIS from `LocalSystem` to use the same user as that set in the impersonate of the Web.Config file and the SignalR process successfully connects to the database!

I don't know yet if this is the perfect solution or why SignalR won't honor the Web.Config impersonate, but it at least gets me going...